# ¿Por que al ingresar en mi login no me valida la contraseña erronea cuando la escribo mal indefinidas veces?

Tags: java

Tengo creado un login en java y mysql al ingresar el usuario correcto y mal la contraseña si me hace la validacion de "contraseña erronea" pero al poner por segunda vez otra contraseña erronea ahi es donde me permite ingresar y ya no me valida que esta erronea y quiero que me siga mandando el mensaje de "contraseña erronea" hasta que ponga la correcta ya me deje ingresar Este es el codigo que estoy poniendo en el boton de ingresar.

//

```
    if(!this.txtUsuario.getText().isEmpty() && !String.copyValueOf(this.ptxtPass.getPassword()).isEmpty())
    {
        String msg = "";
        AppConfig.Estado configUsuario = AppConfig.configUsuario(this.txtUsuario.getText(), String.copyValueOf(this.ptxtPass.getPassword()));

        if(configUsuario == AppConfig.Estado.NO_EXISTE)
        {
            msg = "El usuario: "+this.txtUsuario.getText()+" no existe.";
        }else if(configUsuario == AppConfig.Estado.ERROR_CLAVE)
        {

            msg = "Contraseña Incorrecta";



        }else{
            CEncargadoAlmacen controllerEa = new CEncargadoAlmacen();                
            ArrayList<EncargadoAlmacen> rEa = controllerEa.getRegistrosPorEncargado(AppConfig.getUsuario().getPrimaryKey());
             if(!rEa.isEmpty())
            {                    
                this.cmbAlmacen.setSelectedItem(rEa.get(0).getAlmacen());
                AppConfig.setAlmacen(rEa.get(0).getAlmacen());
            }else{
                asignarAlmacen(AppConfig.getUsuario());
            }
            int op = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Acceso Concedido.\n¿Desea cambiar la configuración actual?",
                                                                "Bienvenido: "+this.txtUsuario.getText(),JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(op == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                this.pnlLogin.setVisible(false);
                this.dcFecha.setEnabled(true);
                this.tftTipoCambio.setEditable(true);
                this.cmbAlmacen.setEnabled(true);
                this.cmbMoneda.setEnabled(true);
                lblLogo.setText("SistemaVenta");
                this.setSize(pnlConfig.getWidth(), this.getHeight()+bntAceptar.getHeight());
                this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                this.bntAceptar.setVisible(true);
                this.bntCancelarConfig.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                initMainWindow();
                this.dispose();
             }
            return;
        }            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Error: no se pudo conectar.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un nombre de usuario y su contraseña", "Error: Datos vacios.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }


}
```

De esta manera se validan las credenciales, para que me mande los mensajes de sesion

```
private static Usuario usuario;
private static Almacen almacen;
private static Moneda moneda;
private static ArrayList<Almacen> almacenes;


public static enum Estado {

    ERROR, NO_EXISTE, ERROR_CLAVE, ACCESO_OK
};

public AppConfig() throws ParserConfigurationException //throws ParserConfigurationException
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbc.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.newDocument();

}

public static Estado configUsuario(String login, String clave) {
    if (usuario == null) {
        return initUsuario(login,clave);
    } else {
        return Estado.ERROR;
    }


}

public static Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public static void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    AppConfig.usuario = usuario;
}

public static Almacen getAlmacen() {
    return almacen;
}

public static void setAlmacen(Almacen almacen) {
    AppConfig.almacen = almacen;
}

public static Moneda getMoneda() {
    return moneda;
}

public static void setMoneda(Moneda moneda) {
    AppConfig.moneda = moneda;
}

public static ArrayList<Almacen> getAlmacenes() {
    return almacenes;
}

public static void setAlmacenes(ArrayList<Almacen> almacenes) {
    AppConfig.almacenes = almacenes;
}

private static Estado initUsuario(String login, String clave) {
    CUsuario cuser = new CUsuario();
    usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario = cuser.getLoginUser(login);
    if (usuario == null) {
        return Estado.NO_EXISTE;
    } else {


        if (clave.equals(usuario.desencriptarPass())) {
            cuser.grabarEnBitacora(usuario);
            if (moneda == null) {
                CMoneda controllerMoneda = new CMoneda();
                controllerMoneda.getRegistros();
                moneda = controllerMoneda.getPredeterminado();
            }

            if (almacen == null) {
                CEncargadoAlmacen controllerEa = new CEncargadoAlmacen();
                ArrayList<EncargadoAlmacen> rEa = controllerEa.getRegistrosPorEncargado(usuario.getPrimaryKey());
                if (!rEa.isEmpty()) {
                    almacenes = new ArrayList<Almacen>();
                    almacen = rEa.get(0).getAlmacen();
                    for (EncargadoAlmacen eat : rEa) {
                        almacenes.add(eat.getAlmacen());
                    }
                }
            }
            return Estado.ACCESO_OK;
        } else {
            return Estado.ERROR_CLAVE;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Tengo la Clase CUsuario de manera independiente

```
public class CUsuario extends JAbstractController{
private Usuario us;
private InputStream itmp;

public CUsuario(){        
    //BaseConexion.init();
}



@Override
public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistros() {
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, null,null);
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistros(Object[] cvl) {        
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, cvl!=null?new String[]{Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO}:null,cvl);
}

public Usuario getLoginUser(String login) {
    ArrayList<Usuario> reg = this.getRegistros(new String[]{},new String[]{"login"},new Object[]{login});
    if(!reg.isEmpty())
    {
        return reg.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistros(String[] columnas,Object[] cvl) {
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, columnas,cvl);
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosPorTipoCargo(String cargo) {
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, new String[]{"tipo_cargo"},new Object[]{cargo});
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosDni(String dni) {
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, new String[]{"dni"},new Object[]{dni});
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosCodigo(String codigo) {
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, new String[]{"codigo"},new Object[]{codigo});
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosLogin(String login) {
    return this.getRegistros(new String[]{}, new String[]{"login"},new Object[]{login});
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosFecha(long valor) {
    return this.getRegistrosMn(new String[]{}, new String[]{"fec_registro"},new Object[]{valor});
}

public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosFecha(long valor1,long valor) {
    return this.getRegistrosMn(new String[]{}, new String[]{"fec_registro","fec_registro"},new Object[]{valor1,valor});
}

@Override
public Usuario getRegistro() {
    ArrayList<Usuario> registros = this.getRegistros();
    return registros.get(0);
}

public Usuario getRegitro(String id)
{
    ArrayList<Usuario> registros = this.getRegistros(new String[]{"dni"},new Object[]{id});
    return registros.get(0);
}


/**
 * 
 * @param mdl modelo
 * @param opcion si true llenara el modelos con todos los datos, de lo contrario solo obtendra la clave primaria.
 * @return 
 */
@Override
public JAbstractModelBD getRegistro(JAbstractModelBD mdl,boolean opcion) {
    us = (Usuario)mdl;
    CriterioSQL criterio = new CriterioSQL(Usuario.nt);
    criterio.setSelect("idu,dni,codigo,login,nombre,apellidos,clave,salt,fono,sexo,tipo_cargo,fec_registro,fec_baja");
    criterio.addCondicion("dni", us.getDni());
    //sql = "select idu,dni,codigo,login,nombre,apellidos,clave,salt,fono,sexo,tipo_cargo,fec_registro,fec_baja from "+us.getNombreTabla()+" where dni = '"+us.getDni()+"'";
    try {
        rs =BaseConexion.getConexion().createStatement().executeQuery(criterio.getConsultaSQL());
        if(rs.next())
        {
            us.setPrimaryKey(rs.getInt(1));
            us.setIdu(rs.getInt(1));
            if(opcion) 
            {
               us.setDni(rs.getString(2));
               us.setCodigo(rs.getString(3));
               us.setLogin(rs.getString(4));
               us.setNombre(rs.getString(5));
               us.setApellidos(rs.getString(6));
               us.setClave(rs.getString(7));
               us.setSalt(rs.getString(8));
               us.setFono(rs.getString(9));
               us.setSexo(rs.getString(10));
               us.setTipoCargo(rs.getString(11));
               us.setFecRegistro(rs.getLong(12));
               us.setFecBaja(rs.getLong(13));
            }
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return us;
}

@Override
public JAbstractModelBD buscarRegistro(Object cvl) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public boolean guardarRegistro(JAbstractModelBD mdl) {

    Usuario usr = (Usuario)mdl;
    int gravado = 0;
    String campos = Usuario.NO_FULL_NOM_CAMPOS;

    Object[] valores = {usr.getDni(), usr.getCodigo(),
               usr.getLogin(),
               usr.getNombre(),
               usr.getApellidos(),
               usr.getFoto(null),
               usr.getClave(),
               usr.getSalt(),
               usr.getFechaNacimiento(),
               usr.getFono(),
               usr.getFono2(),
               usr.getCelular(),
               usr.getNextel(),
               usr.getEmail(),
               usr.getSexo(null),
               usr.getTipoCargo(),
               usr.getDescipcion(),
               usr.getActivo(),                   
               usr.getFecRegistro(),
               usr.getFecBaja()};

       gravado = this.agregarRegistroPs(Usuario.nt, this.stringToArray(campos, ","), valores);

    if(gravado==1)
    {
        //getRegitro(usr.getDni());
        try{
            this.grabarBitacora(this.getUltimoUsuario());
        }catch(SQLException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}            
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}

@Override
public int actualizarRegistro(JAbstractModelBD mdl) {
   Usuario usr = (Usuario)mdl;
    int gravado = 0;
    String campos = Usuario.SIN_FOTO_CLAVE;

    Object[] valores = {usr.getDni(), usr.getCodigo(),
               usr.getLogin(),
               usr.getNombre(),
               usr.getApellidos(),
               usr.getFechaNacimiento(),
               usr.getFono(),
               usr.getFono2(),
               usr.getCelular(),
               usr.getNextel(),
               usr.getEmail(),
               usr.getSexo(null),
               usr.getTipoCargo(),
               usr.getDescipcion(),
               usr.getActivo(),                   
               usr.getFecRegistro(),
               usr.getFecBaja(),usr.getPrimaryKey()};
    gravado = this.actualizarRegistroPs(Usuario.nt, this.adjuntarSimbolo(campos, ",", "?")+Ex.WHERE+Usuario.COLUMNA_PK+" = ? ", valores);
    return gravado;
}

public int actualizarConFoto(JAbstractModelBD mdl) {
   Usuario usr = (Usuario)mdl;
    int gravado = 0;
    String campos = Usuario.CON_FOTO;

    Object[] valores = {usr.getDni(), usr.getCodigo(),
               usr.getLogin(),
               usr.getNombre(),
               usr.getApellidos(),
               usr.getFoto(null),
               usr.getFechaNacimiento(),
               usr.getFono(),
               usr.getFono2(),
               usr.getCelular(),
               usr.getNextel(),
               usr.getEmail(),
               usr.getSexo(null),
               usr.getTipoCargo(),
               usr.getDescipcion(),
               usr.getActivo(),                   
               usr.getFecRegistro(),
               usr.getFecBaja(),usr.getPrimaryKey()};
    gravado = this.actualizarRegistroPs(Usuario.nt, this.adjuntarSimbolo(campos, ",", "?")+Ex.WHERE+Usuario.COLUMNA_PK+" = ? ", valores);


    return gravado;
}

public int actualizarPass(JAbstractModelBD mdl) {
   Usuario usr = (Usuario)mdl;
    int gravado = 0;
    String campos = "clave,salt";

    Object[] valores = {usr.getClave(),usr.getSalt(),usr.getPrimaryKey()};
    gravado = this.actualizarRegistroPs(Usuario.nt, this.adjuntarSimbolo(campos, ",", "?")+Ex.WHERE+Usuario.COLUMNA_PK+" = ? ", valores);

    return gravado;
}

public int grabarEnBitacora(Usuario us)
{
    try{
        return this.grabarBitacora(us);
    }catch(SQLException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    return -1;
}
private int grabarBitacora(Usuario us) throws SQLException 
{

        Calendar cr = Calendar.getInstance();
        Bitacora bt = getBitacora(us);
        sql = "INSERT INTO gv_bitacora ("+Bitacora.COLUMNAS_NO_ID+")"+
        " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        this.ps = BaseConexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1,us.getPrimaryKey()); 
        ps.setString(2, System.getProperty("os.name"));
        ps.setString(3, System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        ps.setString(4, System.getProperty("os.version"));
        ps.setString(5, System.getProperty("user.name"));
        if(bt!=null)
        {
            ps.setLong(6, bt.getFechaActividad());
        }else{
            ps.setLong(6, cr.getTime().getTime());
        }
        ps.setLong(7, cr.getTime().getTime());
        return ps.executeUpdate();            

}

private Bitacora getBitacora(Usuario us) 
{
    try {
        Bitacora bt = new Bitacora();
        sql = "select * from gv_bitacora where idusuario = "+us.getPrimaryKey()+" order by fecha_actividad desc limit 1";
        rs =BaseConexion.getConexion().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next())
        {
            bt.setIdbitacora(rs.getLong(1));
            bt.setIdusuario(rs.getInt(2));
            bt.setOs(rs.getString(3));
            bt.setArquitectura(rs.getString(4));
            bt.setVersion(rs.getString(5));
            bt.setUsuario(rs.getString(6));
            bt.setUltimaActividad(rs.getLong(7));
            bt.setFechaActividad(rs.getLong(8));
            return bt;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public Usuario getRegistroPorPk(Integer id)
{
    try {
        rs =  this.selectPorPk(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_PK, id);
        while(rs.next())
        {
             us = new Usuario();
               us.setPrimaryKey(rs.getInt(1));
               us.setIdu(rs.getInt(1));
               us.setDni(rs.getString(2));
               us.setCodigo(rs.getString(3));
               us.setLogin(rs.getString(4));
               us.setNombre(rs.getString(5));
               us.setApellidos(rs.getString(6));
               us.setClave(rs.getString(8));
               us.setSalt(rs.getString(9));
               us.setFechaNacimiento(rs.getLong(10));
               us.setFono(rs.getString(11));
               us.setFono2(rs.getString(12));
               us.setCelular(rs.getString(13));
               us.setNextel(rs.getString(14));
               us.setEmail(rs.getString(15));
               us.setSexo(rs.getString(16));
               us.setTipoCargo(rs.getString(17));
               us.setDescipcion(rs.getString(18));
               us.setActivo(rs.getInt(19));                   
               us.setFecRegistro(rs.getLong(20));
               us.setFecBaja(rs.getLong(21));   

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return us;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistros(String[] campos, String[] columnaId, Object[] id) {
    ArrayList<Usuario> rgs = new ArrayList<Usuario>();        
    try {

        if(id != null)
        { 
           this.numRegistros = this.getNumeroRegistros(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO, id);
        }else
        {
           this.numRegistros = this.getNumeroRegistros(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO);               
           if(rs.isClosed())
           {
               System.out.println("resultset esta cerrado...");
           }
        }
        rs = this.getRegistros(Usuario.nt,campos,columnaId,id);
        if(this.numRegistros<finalPag)
       {
          finalPag =  this.numRegistros;
       }
        if(finalPag>inicioPag)
        {
            inicioPag -= (finalPag-inicioPag)-1;
        }
        Usuario us = null;
        while(rs.next())
        {
               us = new Usuario();
               us.setPrimaryKey(rs.getInt(1));   
               us.setIdu(rs.getInt(1));
               us.setDni(rs.getString(2));
               us.setCodigo(rs.getString(3));
               us.setLogin(rs.getString(4));
               us.setNombre(rs.getString(5));
               us.setApellidos(rs.getString(6));
               us.setClave(rs.getString(8));
               us.setSalt(rs.getString(9));
               us.setFechaNacimiento(rs.getLong(10));
               us.setFono(rs.getString(11));
               us.setFono2(rs.getString(12));
               us.setCelular(rs.getString(13));
               us.setNextel(rs.getString(14));
               us.setEmail(rs.getString(15));
               us.setSexo(rs.getString(16));
               us.setTipoCargo(rs.getString(17));
               us.setDescipcion(rs.getString(18));
               us.setActivo(rs.getInt(19));                   
               us.setFecRegistro(rs.getLong(20));
               us.setFecBaja(rs.getLong(21));                
             rgs.add(us);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rgs;
}
public Usuario getUltimoUsuario()
{
   Usuario us2 = null;
   rs = this.getUltimoRegistro(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_PK);
   try{

        while(rs.next())
        {
               us2 = new Usuario();
               us2.setPrimaryKey(rs.getInt(1));   
               us2.setIdu(rs.getInt(1));
               us2.setDni(rs.getString(2));
               us2.setCodigo(rs.getString(3));
               us2.setLogin(rs.getString(4));
               us2.setNombre(rs.getString(5));
               us2.setApellidos(rs.getString(6));
               us2.setClave(rs.getString(8));
               us2.setSalt(rs.getString(9));
               us2.setFechaNacimiento(rs.getInt(10));
               us2.setFono(rs.getString(11));
               us2.setFono2(rs.getString(12));
               us2.setCelular(rs.getString(13));
               us2.setNextel(rs.getString(14));
               us2.setEmail(rs.getString(15));
               us2.setSexo(rs.getString(16));
               us2.setTipoCargo(rs.getString(17));
               us2.setDescipcion(rs.getString(18));
               us2.setActivo(rs.getInt(19));                   
               us2.setFecRegistro(rs.getLong(20));
               us2.setFecBaja(rs.getLong(21));               

        }
   }catch(SQLException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   return us2;
}

 public ArrayList<Usuario> getRegistrosMn(String[] campos, String[] columnaId, Object[] id) {
    ArrayList<Usuario> rgs = new ArrayList<Usuario>();        
    try {

        if(id != null)
        { 
           this.numRegistros = this.getNumeroRegistros(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO, id);
        }else
        {
           this.numRegistros = this.getNumeroRegistros(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO);               
           if(rs.isClosed())
           {
               System.out.println("resultset esta cerrado...");
           }
        }
        rs = this.getRegistrosMn(Usuario.nt,campos,columnaId,id);
        if(this.numRegistros<finalPag)
       {
          finalPag =  this.numRegistros;
       }
        if(finalPag>inicioPag)
        {
            inicioPag -= (finalPag-inicioPag)-1;
        }
        Usuario us = null;
        while(rs.next())
        {
               us = new Usuario();
               us.setPrimaryKey(rs.getInt(1));
               us.setIdu(rs.getInt(1));
               us.setDni(rs.getString(2));
               us.setCodigo(rs.getString(3));
               us.setLogin(rs.getString(4));
               us.setNombre(rs.getString(5));
               us.setApellidos(rs.getString(6));
               us.setClave(rs.getString(8));
               us.setSalt(rs.getString(9));
               us.setFechaNacimiento(rs.getInt(10));
               us.setFono(rs.getString(11));
               us.setFono2(rs.getString(12));
               us.setCelular(rs.getString(13));
               us.setNextel(rs.getString(14));
               us.setEmail(rs.getString(15));
               us.setSexo(rs.getString(16));
               us.setTipoCargo(rs.getString(17));
               us.setDescipcion(rs.getString(18));
               us.setActivo(rs.getInt(19));                   
               us.setFecRegistro(rs.getLong(20));
               us.setFecBaja(rs.getLong(21));                
             rgs.add(us);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rgs;
}

public boolean existeCodigo(String codigo)
{
    return this.existe(Usuario.nt, "codigo", codigo);
}

public boolean existeDni(String dni)
{
    return this.existe(Usuario.nt, "dni", dni);
}

public boolean existeLogin(String login)
{
    return this.existe(Usuario.nt, "login", login);
}

public String getCodigoUsuario()
{
    return this.getCodigo(Usuario.nt, "codigo");
}

public ImageIcon getFoto(Integer id)
{
    InputStream archivo = this.getArchivo(Usuario.nt, "foto", Usuario.COLUMNA_PK, id); 
    itmp = archivo;
    ImageIcon ii = null;
    if(archivo!= null)
    {
        try {
             BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(archivo);
              ii = new ImageIcon(read);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return ii;        
}
public InputStream getDatoFoto()
{

    return this.itmp;
}

public int getNumeroRegistros()
{
    return this.getNumeroRegistros(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_PK);
}

public int activarUsuario(Usuario us)
{
    return this.eliminacionTemporal(Usuario.nt, Usuario.COLUMNA_ACTIVO, Usuario.COLUMNA_PK, us.getPrimaryKey(), 1);
}
```

}introducir el código aquí

Comment: Puedes colocar como haces la validación de las credenciales. Intenta colocar todo el código que esta involucrado para que te puedan ayudar de mejor manera y también tener una mayor visión del problema.

Comment: Listo, espero haber subido el codigo necesario.

Comment: La clase CUsuario esta en otro archivo ?

Comment: Si la tengo como una clase independiente

Comment: Es decir no me la compara  la contraseña con la base de datos  y me permite accesar, lo unico que valida es el usuario como podria hacerle para validar contraseña